# RavenDB Linq Invalid Operation .ToUpperInvariant()

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I'm trying to use `ToUpperInvariant()` within a LINQ query with RavenDB. I'm getting an **InvalidOperationException**:

> Cannot understand how to translate server.Name.ToUpperInvariant().

The query is below. What needs to happen in order for me to be able to match by name here? Is this possible within a query using RavenDB?

```
public ApplicationServer GetByName(string serverName)
{
    return QuerySingleResultAndCacheEtag(session => session.Query<ApplicationServer>()
        .Where(server => server.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == serverName.ToUpperInvariant()).FirstOrDefault())
        as ApplicationServer;
}

protected static EntityBase QuerySingleResultAndCacheEtag(Func<IDocumentSession, EntityBase> func)
{
    if (func == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("func"); }

    using (IDocumentSession session = Database.OpenSession())
    {
        EntityBase entity = func.Invoke(session);
        if (entity == null) { return null; }
        CacheEtag(entity, session);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the exception states, the server does not understand `ToUpperInvariant()`. As far as I know, RavenDB uses a custom *LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer*, so by default queries are case-insensitive. [See the RavenDB documentation on analyzers](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/indexes/using-analyzers) for more details.

Comment: Ok, cool, I was trying to compare by converting to upper case, and that wasn't even necessary. I just tried it without converting and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do the same thing; didn't know about this at all. Doh.

Comment: Was expecting "programming language like" comparison behavior too and ran into the same issue. I guess I should have expected "Database like" comparison which is usually to ignore case by default. Thanks!